# Poor fit of variograms in spatial GLS models

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, variogram

I run into some problems when investigating correlation structures in spatial GLS models, precisely that fitted variogram does not fit residuals.

Template data can be downloaded here: http://harmackova.wz.cz/other/temp_data.csv

R code:

```
temp.data <- read.csv('temp_data.csv')[-1] # read data

model.gls <- gls(response ~ predictor.1 + predictor.2 + predictor.3 + predictor.4, data = temp.data) # simple gls
model.gls.spat <- gls(response ~ predictor.1 + predictor.2 + predictor.3 + predictor.4, data = temp.data, corr = corExp(form = ~x+y)) # gls with correlation structure (Exponential model has the lowest AIC)

plot(Variogram(model.gls, form = ~x+y)) # plot variograms
plot(Variogram(model.gls.spat, form = ~x+y))
```

The resulting variogram looks like this:

[image]

It does not fit at all.
When inspecting other correlation structures they also show poor fits.

Then I took a look at Moran's I and how well did this model dealt with spatial autocorrelation:

```
corr <- data.frame(no = 1:20)
corr$gls <- correlog(x = temp.data$x, y = temp.data$y, z = model.gls$residuals, increment = 2, resamp = 100, quiet = T)$correlation
corr$gls.spat <- correlog(x = temp.data$x, y = temp.data$y, z = model.gls.spat$residuals, increment = 2, resamp = 100, quiet = T)$correlation
plot(corr$gls ~ corr$no, pch = 1, xlab = 'Distance', ylab = 'Moran I')
points(corr$gls.spat ~ corr$no, pch = 16)
legend('bottomleft', c('GLS', 'spatial GLS'), pch = c(1,16), cex = 0.7)
```

[image]

Residual spatial autocorrelation even increased in the spatial model.

I also tried using LME instead of GLS, but results were similar:

```
model.lme <- lme(response ~ predictor.1 + predictor.2 + predictor.3 + predictor.4, data = temp.data, random = ~ 1|region)
model.lme.spat <- lme(response ~ predictor.1 + predictor.2 + predictor.3 + predictor.4, data = temp.data, random = ~ 1|region, corr = corExp(form = ~x+y))

plot(Variogram(model.lme.spat, form = ~x+y))

corr$lme <- correlog.nc(x = temp.data$x, y = temp.data$y, z = model.lme$residuals, increment = 2, resamp = 100, quiet = T)$correlation
corr$lme.spat <- correlog.nc(x = temp.data$x, y = temp.data$y, z = model.lme.spat$residuals, increment = 2, resamp = 100, quiet = T)$correlation
plot(corr$lme ~ corr$no, pch = 1)
points(corr$lme.spat ~ corr$no, pch = 16)
```

I would like to know what causes this behaviour and how can I better fit some correlation structure to actually match my data.

Comment: Check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109824/variogram-model-fit-compatability-among-geor-gstat-and-nlme-packages-in-r. Maybe you can try `geoR` or `gstat` packages as an alternative. Unfortunately, didn't found how to include a *correlation structure* using those packages.